# is there any similar function in numpy(python) with Vector3.TransformCoordinate in SharpDX (c#)?

Tags: python, c#, numpy, sharpdx

i am trying to transform some codes from c# to python, but i have a problem that what is `Vector3.TransformCoordinate` doing, is there any similar way to do this function?

here is the part of code i am confuse on

```cs
using SharpDX;

namespace Test
{
    internal class Program
    {
        public float[] DoSomething(float[] rawMatrix,Vector2 pos2D,float width,float height)
        {
            var viewProjectionMatrix = new Matrix();
            for (var i = 0; i < 16; i++) viewProjectionMatrix[i] = rawMatrix[i];
            viewProjectionMatrix.Invert();
            var pos3D = new Vector3 {
                X = pos2D.X / width * 2.0f - 1.0f,
                Y = -(pos2D.Y / height * 2.0f - 1.0f),
                Z = 0
            };
            Vector3.TransformCoordinate(ref pos3D, ref viewProjectionMatrix, out var camPos);
            pos3D.Z = 1;
            Vector3.TransformCoordinate(ref pos3D, ref viewProjectionMatrix, out var camPosOne);
            var clipPos = camPosOne - camPos;
            clipPos.Normalize();
            return clipPos.ToArray();
        }
    }
}
```

here is the code after i try to translate(of course, it dont work as what i wish)

```py
import numpy as np


def do_something_in_python(raw_matrix: list[float], pos2d: list[float], width: float, height: float):
    viewProjectionMatrix = np.linalg.inv(np.array(raw_matrix).reshape((4,4)))
    pos3d = np.array([
        pos2d[0] / width * 2 - 1,
        pos2d[1] / height * 2 - 1,
        0
    ])
    camPos = viewProjectionMatrix * pos3d
    pos3d[2] = 1
    camPosOne = viewProjectionMatrix * pos3d
    return np.linalg.norm(camPosOne - camPos).tolist()
```

Answer (score 0):

From the documentation of [TransformCoordinate](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/windows/desktop/bb324381(v=vs.85))

> This method transforms the source vector, source (x, y, z, 1), or all vectors in the vector parameter, by the matrix sourceMatrix, projecting the result back into w = 1.

i.e. you would create a vector 4 with a one in the w-field

```
pos4d = np.array([
    pos2d[0] / width * 2 - 1,
    pos2d[1] / height * 2 - 1,
    0,
    1
])
```

and then multiply with the transform, and divide the x/y/z fields with the w-field

```
camPosTmp = viewProjectionMatrix * pos4d
camPos = np.array([
    camPosTmp[0] / camPosTmp[3]
    camPosTmp[1] / camPosTmp[3]
    camPosTmp[2] / camPosTmp[3]
])
```

Note that my Python is rusty, so this is a best guess on how you would write it.